# WinJS : Binding ListView itemDataSource with List.groups.dataSource fails

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am facing a really annoying behaviour of grouped `WinJS.Binding.List`.

When trying to create a SemanticZoom, i fill (in markup) the zoomed-out view items and zoomed-in view headers with the same data from a `list.groups.dataSource` :

```
<div id="semanticZoomDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom" data-win-options="{ initiallyZoomedOut: true }">
    <div id="zoomedInListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
        data-win-options="{
            itemDataSource: Data.myCategories.dataSource,
            itemTemplate: select('#zoomedInItemTemplate'),
            groupDataSource: Data.myCategories.groups.dataSource,
            groupHeaderTemplate: select('#zoomedInHeaderTemplate')
        }"
    ></div>
    <div id="zoomedOutListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{
            itemDataSource: Data.myCategories.groups.dataSource,
            itemTemplate: select('#zoomedOutItemTemplate')
        }"
    ></div>              
</div>
```

This code works or doesn't depending on my data :

- if i use my real-world data, which is a 3-level tree of categories generated from remote data (i call WinJS.xhr), the zoomed-out ListView fails to bind its itemDataSource with the groups. So my SemanticZoom is well processed but the zoomed-out view is empty.

  More precisely, in my zoomed-out view :

  1. This code fails :

     ```
     data-win-options="{
         itemDataSource: Data.myCategories.groups.dataSource,
         itemTemplate: select('#zoomedOutItemTemplate')
     }"
     ```
  2. This code works but displays the detailed categories while i want the groups :

     ```
     data-win-options="{
         itemDataSource: Data.myCategories.dataSource,
         itemTemplate: select('#zoomedOutItemTemplate')
     }"
     ```
  3. This code works, which proves my groups are well-formed when i call `createGrouped` earlier, but it makes no sense for me to do this since i need my zoomed-out view to display only main groups in which to zoom :

     ```
     data-win-options="{
         itemDataSource: Data.myCategories.dataSource,
         itemTemplate: select('#zoomedOutItemTemplate'),
         groupDataSource: Data.myCategories.groups.dataSource
     }"
     ```
- if i use sample and simpler data, everything works fine, and i can use my SemanticZoom.

Since the bug seems to happen depending on my input data, below are two snippets of the raw data with which i define a `WinJS.Binding.List` :

1. The real-world data, not working : (json-stringified from my generated data)

   ```
   var myCategories = [{
       "id":"CAT_1_1",
       "title":"Category 1.1",
       "groupKey":0,
       "groupId":"CAT_1",
       "groupTitle":"Category 1" },
   {...}];
   ```
2. The sample data, working : (hand-written)

   ```
   var myCategories = [
       { group: 1, id: "1.1", title: "item 1.1" },
       { group: 1, id: "1.2", title: "item 1.2" },
   ];
   ```

FYI : 
- the bug doesn't come from the templates, i checked.

Thanks for your help, i have struggled with this one for 2 days now...

Comment: Nice find. I would recommend putting your answer in the "answer" section and mark it as correct. Otherwise, people who has similar confusion could skip this Q becuz there is “no” answer. Or someone tried to answer could spent 5 min reading and understanding your question only got to the end knowing that you solved it already. Just a kind suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem :

`WinJS.Binding.List.createGrouped()` must receive a `groupKey(itemData)` function as parameter, which returns a key to identify the group for each item.

**The returned key must be a STRING, while my real data was returning an INT**. Changing this solved the problem.

This is not mentioned in common Windows 8 quickstarts and confusion may come from the `compare(leftKey, rightKey)` function which uses group keys to calculate a sorting criteria and returns a number.

Hope this will help.